# Calculation within pandas DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Thats the data]

Hi everyone,

As we are absolut starters in programming, we do have some problems that you might consider pretty basic.

We need to find a solution for the following problem:

We have a list that shows different products with their names, if they left the stock or came into it and in which amount that was the case.

Now we need to calculate the stock by "just" subtract the outgoing goods from the incoming ones. That's the point where we (already) can't get further. So I'm open to all your recommendations.

Thank you for your input.

```
df= pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=["uhrzeit"])


#delete "__dt" 
df = df.drop("__dt", axis = 1)
df = df[['uhrzeit', 'produkt_oder_strichcode', 'menge', 'warenein_oder_ausgang']]

#sort by date
df = df.sort_values(by=["uhrzeit"])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

Comment: Please can you post some of your data by typing df.head(20) in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the incoming data using:

```
incoming = df["warenein_oder_ausgang"] == "Wareneingang"
```

You can find the outgoing products using the inverse:

```
~incoming
```

Then, you can use the pandas groupby function to group by the product codes, take the sum and subtract the outgoing products from the incoming products:

```
df[incoming].groupby("produkt_oder_strichcode").sum() - df[~incoming].groupby("produkt_oder_strichcode").sum()
```